# xarray groupby coordinates and non coordinate variables

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-xarray

I am trying to calculate the distribution of a variable in a xarray. I can achieve what I am looking for by converting the xarray to a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
lon = np.linspace(0,10,11)
lat =  np.linspace(0,10,11)
time = np.linspace(0,10,1000)


temperature = 3*np.random.randn(len(lat),len(lon),len(time))

ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        temperature=(["lat", "lon", "time"], temperature),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        lon=lon,
        lat=lat,
        time=time,
    ),
)

bin_t = np.linspace(-10,10,21)
DS = ds.to_dataframe()
DS.loc[:,'temperature_bin'] = pd.cut(DS['temperature'],bin_t,labels=(bin_t[0:-1]+bin_t[1:])*0.5)
DS_stats = DS.reset_index().groupby(['lat','lon','temperature_bin']).count()
ds_stats = DS_stats.to_xarray()

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:          (lat: 11, lon: 11, temperature_bin: 20)
Coordinates:
  * lat              (lat) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0
  * lon              (lon) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0
  * temperature_bin  (temperature_bin) float64 -9.5 -8.5 -7.5 ... 7.5 8.5 9.5
Data variables:
    time             (lat, lon, temperature_bin) int64 0 1 8 13 18 ... 9 5 3 0
    temperature      (lat, lon, temperature_bin) int64 0 1 8 13 18 ... 9 5 3 0
```

Is there a way to generate ds_stats without converting to a dataframe? I have tried to use groupby_bins but this does not preserve coordinates.

```
print(ds.groupby_bins('temperature',bin_t).count())

distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 21% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:           (temperature_bins: 20)
Coordinates:
  * temperature_bins  (temperature_bins) object (-10.0, -9.0] ... (9.0, 10.0]
Data variables:
    temperature       (temperature_bins) int64 121 315 715 1677 ... 709 300 116
```

Comment: Are you hoping to preserve the lat, lon, and time or just lat, lon, getting the frequency distribution over time?

Comment: I would like to calculate the change in distribution on a seasonal basis but I think I know how to do this using resample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [xhistogram](https://xhistogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) may be helpful.

With the same definitions as you had set above,

```
from xhistogram import xarray as xhist
ds_stats = xhist.histogram(ds.temperature, bins=bin_t,dim=['time'])
```

should do the trick.

The one difference is that it returns a `DataArray`, not a `Dataset`, so if you want to do it for multiple variables, you'll have to do it separately for each one and then recombine, I believe.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This suggests that there is no "native" solution within xarray. I didn't know about xhist and this seems to do exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: np!

Yeah... fwiw, the devs of xhistogram are also heavily involved with xarray (see e.g. the discussion [here](https://discourse.pangeo.io/t/xarray-dataset-grouby-bins-without-squishing-other-dimensions/1692/5)). Xarray generally has very specific ideas about what they want to directly include in the core, and what they would prefer to be outsourced to other packages, and in this case people seem to want to keep this separate.